# WordPress theme Child CSS not overriding Parent even though Child CSS is loaded after

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using the Shapely theme.

I'm enqueueing my child theme's stylesheet like so:

```
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'shapely-style'; //

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

And in my page source, my child theme style is definitely loading AFTER the parent in the `<head>`.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='shapely-style-css'  href='http://mydomainname.com/wp-content/themes/shapely/style.css?ver=4.7.3' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='child-style-css'  href='http://mydomainname.com/wp-content/themes/child-theme-name/style.css?ver=4.7.3' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

However, when inspecting my page, my parent styles are still overriding my child theme styles. See below screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because your parent theme's CSS has a higher specificity.

If you replace `.post-title` with the same selector the parent theme is using (`.post-content .entry-content .post-title`) it will override the parent settings. Not because it has a higher specificity but because it comes after the same selector, so it wins out.

**Specificity values of posted selectors:**

`.post-title` = `0 0 1 0`

`.post-content .entry-content .post-title` = `0 0 3 0`

- [Calculating a Selector's Specificity](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity)
- [Handy Specificity Calculator](http://specificity.keegan.st/)

Comment: [This is a way to learn more about specificity](https://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html).